# Qt - Recursive repaint needed, how?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, graphics

I have the following code:

```
paintGL()
{

    if(mouse_was_clicked)
    {
       ... do the color picking with openGL to identify a clicked element

       ... !!! now I need to call again paintGL() to switch the selected element from the 
              old one to the new one but I can't create a recursive cycle!
    }
    else
    {
       ... normal code to draw the scene and the selected element in red ...
    }
}
```

As the lines suggest, I need a way to call once more the paint event.. is there any way to accomplish this without creating a potential livelock? Something like deferring a new paint event?

Comment: Without looking to deep into what you are doing... Could you just set a flag so that when it comes back around again you can false the flag and prevent the recursion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the control flow within your `paintGL()` is that simple, just make sure that the contens currently being in the `else` block are executed in every case:

```
void MyWidget::paintGL()
{
    if(mouse_was_clicked)
    {
        ... do the color picking with openGL to identify a clicked element
    }

    ... normal code to draw the scene and the selected element in red ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit hard to tell exactly what you're doing here.

If you're trying to setup a display widget (a color picker) when paintGL detects a mouse button has been clicked, you've mixed up your events. You should make a separate action for handling a mouseclick, which sets up flags/variables and triggers a repaint. IE, move the mouse-event handling out of the repaint callback.

I could easily have misunderstood your problem here, however... if so I apologize.

As a general rule, though, if you find yourself needing a recursive repaint in QT, you're probably working against, rather than with, the system.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for (much simpler), but thank you for your help and +1 for your effort